# replacement for rospy.Time(0) in ROS2?

Tags: ros, python, ros2, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to lookup the latest transformation in a tf buffer. In ROS 1 used rospy.Time(0), but I haven't found anything about how it works in ROS2.

Here is a snippet of the code to understand in the context:

```
tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tf_buffer)

dur = Duration()
dur.sec = 10
dur.nsec = 0

transform_odom_base_link = tf_buffer.lookup_transform(target_frame='base_link',
                                        source_frame='odom',
                                        time=UNKNOWN
                                        timeout=dur)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388194/replacement-for-rospy.time(0)-in-ros2?/) by [janolus](https://answers.ros.org/users/86688/janolus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

with `rclpy.time.Time()` it seems to work

---

Originally posted by [janolus](https://answers.ros.org/users/86688/janolus/) with karma: 36 on 2021-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1